# Laravel Forge SSL Your connection is not private

Tags: laravel, ssl

I am experincing a strange issue after deploying my site and installing a ssl certificate.

I contacted other people who live in other cities and they can access the website. However every time I access it I get:

```
Your connection is not private, NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

I tried, clearing chrome cache, cookies..., reseting the dns resolver cache of my machine, emptying cache and hard reloading...

I am using Laravel Forge, Digital Ocean and a Comodo Certificate.

Regards,
Diego

Comment: Have you activated the certificate? Are the other people accessing though the non-https url? Which browser are you using?

Comment: certificate is activated, other people are using https url and I am using chrome

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular reason to suspect Laravel of causing this issue. One easy way to check is to upload a simple .txt file and then load that into your browser with https.

If the problem persists, then you should contact your host and ask them for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I used forge for my laravel project and name.com as domain provider.

I did the following steps:

- I made Certificate signing request from forge.
- I took the CSR to name.com and issued SSL certificate with the same information.
- I activated the CSR installed in my laravel project's server with the SSL server certificate and intermediate certificate as well.
- I installed it on the server and ran `php artisan optimize`.
- I updated the environment in forge to have the URL of the domain with prefix `https://`.
- I waited for 5 minutes and refreshed the page of the domain.

Now it works better than ever, hope I could help here.